# C++:error syntax error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matrix, vector, dictionary

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>  // C++ header file for I/O
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>       /* round, floor, ceil, trunc */
#include <map>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int Q[10][10]={
    {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1},  
    {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},  
    {1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0},  
    {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},  
    {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},  
    {1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1}
  };

    std::multimap<int,int> mymap;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> myvector;

    for(i = 0 ; i<10 ;i++)
    {
        int key = 0;
        for(j = 0 ; j<10 ;j++)
        {
            key += Q[i][j] << j;
        }
        mymap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(key,i));
    }

    int maxCardinalite = 0;
    int nbCategorie = 0;

    for( auto iter = mymap.begin() ; iter != mymap.end() ; iter = mymap.upper_bound(iter->first) )
    {
        std::vector<int> mylist;
        for(auto iter2 = iter ; iter2 != mymap.upper_bound(iter->first) ; ++iter2)
        {
            mylist.push_back(iter2->second);
            maxCardinalite = (maxCardinalite > mylist.size()) ? maxCardinalite : mylist.size();
        }
        myvector.push_back(mylist);
        nbCategorie++;
    }

    int* R = (int*)malloc(maxCardinalite*nbCategorie*sizeof(int));
    ZeroMemory( R,maxCardinalite*nbCategorie*sizeof(int));
    std::sort(begin(myvector),end(myvector),[](std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b){return a[0]<b[0];});

    int ligne = 0;
    for( const auto& i : myvector ) // i
    {
        int colone = 0;
        for( auto j : i) // j : i
        {
            R[ligne*maxCardinalite+colone] = j; // i
            colone++;
        }
        ligne++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors. Can you help me please?

> source3.cc(113): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'
>   source3.cc(113): error C2530: 'i' : references must be initialized
>   source3.cc(113): error C3531: 'i': a symbol whose type contains 'auto'
>   must have an initializer source3.cc(114): error C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before '{'

Comment: It'll be pretty hard to help you with an error on line 113 when what you posted is only 84 lines long. Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying you should post all the code, just the relevant part with the offending line marked out.

Comment: VS 2010 doesn't support range-loops, to my knowledge.

Comment: This code compile in VS2013. Upgrade.

Comment: maybe include some more headers

Answer (score 0):

Accoording to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable) the C++ compiler of Visual Studio 2010 does not support range-based for loops.

The error messages are about its inability to parse such.

Answer (score -1):

I provided all the code. Indeed, the error is in this block :

```
for( const auto& i : myvector ) // i
    {
        int colone = 0;
        for( auto j : i) // j : i
        {
            R[ligne*maxCardinalite+colone] = j; // i
            colone++;
        }
        ligne++;
    }
```

> 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(61): warning
>   C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(72): error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':' 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(72): error
>   C2530: 'i' : references must be initialized 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(72): error
>   C3531: 'i': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an
>   initializer 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(73): error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(75): error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':' 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(75): error
>   C3531: 'j': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an
>   initializer 1>c:\documents and
>   settings\client\bureau\essai\presence\presence\source3.cc(76): error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 1>

Comment: edit your question to provide additional info - don't post an answer